# Android NDK mangles relative path on windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create an Android Studio wrapper around C code and am running into a problem with the NDK. Because the C code is from a 3rd party project, I am trying to not move the code location and have the project in a subdirectory of the repository and as such have to not use the build in call to the NDK and its autogenerated make file. The NDK call works correctly, but I get the following error:

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/some_relative_path/jni/../../../../core.c', needed by `C:/some_relative_path/obj/local/armeabi/objs/my_module/C_/some_relative_path/jni/__/__/__/__/core.o'.  Stop.
```

As you can see, the object path has been mangled such that `:` and `..` have been turned into underscores.

I had to add a jni folder to my project and place the `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files in it to satisfy the path appending of the NDK Gradle plugin. As a result the `jni` folder had no source files in it. Since I found several links on google talking about needing more than one source file, I added two dummy source files to the `jni` directory.

Among other things, my `Android.mk` file contains the following:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/NDKBug1.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/NDKBug2.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../core.c \
```

I'm looking to see if anyone can help me with either this path issue directly, or perhaps suggest an alternative way of setting things up.

Comment: have you tried going thru the examples in the NDK? if you do that and observe expressions in android.mk and look at the folders used, it may give a better idea of inner workings of NDK so u can then build ur proj.  NDK gets u into cygwin on windows.

Answer (score 0):

The file names in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` are supposed to be relative to the local directory, so you need to remove the `$(LOCAL_PATH)/` prefix - then it should work.

I haven't heard about a bug requiring to have source files in the local dir though, so I think you can get rid of them.